# Can I use a Cosina AF 28-300mm f/4-6.3 with a Nikon D5100 if I focus manually?

Tags: autofocus, nikon-d5100, focus-motor

The Cosina AF 28-300mm is an autofocus zoom for Nikon F-mount (body must have AF motor).

Can I still use it with the D5100, provide that I will have to manual focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As you say, the lack of AF motor in the D5100 body means you will have to manually focus, but the lens will otherwise function just fine.